# How to Replace or Remove HTML Editor styles in the Sharepoint 2010 Ribbon

Tags: css, sharepoint-2010

I want to replace the HTML Editor styles in the HTML Style dropdown on the editor ribbon with styles of my own creation. According to this MSDN article http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/ms551040.aspx as soon as I start putting classes that begin with the pattern `ms-rteCustom-XXXX`(XXXX being a custom name) into CSS that's loaded in the page, the existing styles should be replaced. I would expect this to leave only my styles in the drop-down, however I can see all of the original Sharepoint styles, and then my styles.

Am I missing something in the documentation, or is it lying to me? As far as I can tell, the original styles come from the corev4.css that's also loaded by the master page, however as my CSS is loaded later, it seems like any styles already in the drop down should be cleared.

Here is one of the new/custom styles in the CSS I'm using;

```
H3.ms-rteElement-H3CompanyName
{
    -ms-name:"Heading 3";
}
.ms-rteElement-H3CompanyName
{
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size: small;
    font-style: normal;
    line-height: normal;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-variant: normal;
    text-transform: none;
    color: #000000;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like the only way to remove elements from the Markup Style drop down list is to modify files in the main Sharepoint hive.  A reset of IIS is probably a good idea after these changes, then ctrl-F5 to fully refresh what the browser is seeing.

This is not normally recommended as these files may change as part of a Sharepoint upgrade, however it seems to be the only way that reliably works.

To remove unwanted elements from the Markup Style dropdown, remove all CSS rules that affect classes named in this pattern `.ms-rteElement-XXXX` . Our own styles for use in this menu are added in one of our own style sheets.

There are four files that need to be modified, two copies of Controls.css and two copies of Corev4.css.

They are located as follows;

```
Controls.css 
C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\14\TEMPLATE\FEATURES\PublishingLayouts\en-us\Controls.css

COREV4.CSS 
C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\14\TEMPLATE\LAYOUTS\1033\STYLES\COREV4.CSS

CONTROLS.CSS 
C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\14\TEMPLATE\LAYOUTS\1033\STYLES\CONTROLS.CSS

COREV4.CSS 
C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\14\TEMPLATE\LAYOUTS\1033\STYLES\Themable\COREV4.CSS
```

Comment: I would avoid overriding core elements.

Comment: should not change the MS provided files.  service packs and cumulative updates could overwrite your changes.

Answer (score 4):

The best way to remove the styles, assuming this is a publishing page, is to modify the control within your page layout.

```
<PublishingWebControls:RichHtmlField FieldName="PublishingPageContent" HasInitialFocus="True" MinimumEditHeight="400px" runat="server" PrefixStyleSheet="customPrefix"/>
```

By declaring a new PrefixStyleSheet it will remove all of the default styles so that you can only provide your own.

Answer (score 3):

Rather than JavaScript, you can also use css to hide Markup Styles.
For example, this is how to hide Heading 1s.

```
#Ribbon\.EditingTools\.CPEditTab\.Paragraph\.ElementWithStyle\.Menu\.Styles #ElementWithStyle0-Menu,
#Ribbon\.EditingTools\.CPEditTab\.Paragraph\.ElementWithStyle\.Menu\.Styles #ElementWithStyle4-Menu
    {display:none;}
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure where you've read that "as soon as custom styles are added, old ones are removed". The way I read the documentation, it correlates to my experience with this - that the custom styles are just added to the bottom of the dropdown list.

What you could do though, is to override the built-in ones with your custom style as well. Just use the exact same name as the OOTB styles and enter your own styles in the CSS file. Example: to override the style "Callout 1", add a rule for .ms-rteElement-Callout1 in your CSS and add your own styling there.

Another option is to write a JavaScript function and attach it to the ribbon resized event using

```
SP.UI.Workspace.add_resized(your_javascript_function_name);
```

Inside your function, you can use a jQuery statement to remove all (or the first X) elements from the dropdown list in the ribbon control.

Comment: Uh, damn, looks like I misread it, it was talking about .ms-rteCustom-XXXX elements. The javascript approach sounds promising, I'll give it a shot.

Comment: Javascript does let me remove items from the list, however they don't render on the page until the dropdown menu is selected. Is there an event that I should be listening for that can then trigger the javascript?

Comment: I'm not entirely sure if I know what you mean - what does not render until what dropdown menu is selected?

Comment: I'm trying to use jquery to select the list-elements of each style and remove them. 
At the time the add_resized event is fired the list of styles does not exist in the page source (and are thus not rendered on the page). As the items in the list don't exist yet, the javascript can't select them for removal, hence asking about an event to listen for. The elements appear when the dropdown is selected.
Or, am I missing something about your original suggestion?

Comment: Ok, now I get it :) The ECMAScript events are not very well documented, unfortunately. But I found another that looks promising:

CUI.Page.PageManager.add_ribbonInited(your_javascript_function_name)

Comment: That one didn't work. I ended up using the approach I answered with to remove all of the Sharepoint styles. Thanks for your help though, I think the approach you've described will be useful for some fine-grained modification of the ribbon.

Answer (score 0):

I would add your CSS to the alternate CSS option under Look and Feel in your site settings. If you dont see the option, turn on publishing options.

Then add the CSS you want. It gets loaded last and to make sure, you can add !important to the styles.

Look here for more details... Half way down the page.

[Sharepoint 2010 Themes and Alternate CSS for overriding Core](http://whitepages.sfintelligence.com/2010/05/using-themes-and-css-with-sharepoint-2010/)

EDIT FOR COMMENT BELOW:

```
$('a#Ribbon.EditingTools.CPEditTab.Markup.ElementWithStyle-Large').click(function(){
  $('a#ElementWithStyle3-Menu').parent().hide();
});
```

Comment: That isn't what I was after. I agree that the solution you've described would work for **overriding** elements (and was one approach that I tried out), however I wanted to **remove** elements. The answer I described above is the only solution I've found thus far.

Comment: I think i also misread the thread a little... You asked above about what to listen for to remove them. Perhaps write some quick jquery to look for the Markup-Styles button click. Ill edit my answer with a code sample.

Answer (score 0):

I finally got this to work using purely Javascript. What I did is register a PageComponent and then add a handler for the appropriate command (In the case of Markup Styles, the command is called 'ElementWithStyleOptionsOpen').

Here is the MSDN documentation about how to develop PageComponents: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff407303.aspx#Y300

In my custom PageComponent class I registered 'ElementWithStyleOptionsOpen' as a GlobalCommand:

```
getGlobalCommands: function () {
    return ['ElementWithStyleOptionsOpen'];
}
```

...And also added it to canHandleCommand:

```
canHandleCommand: function (commandId) {
    if (commandId === 'ElementWithStyleOptionsOpen')  {
        return true;
    }
    else {
        return false;
    }
```

Finally my HandleCommand looks like this:

```
handleCommand: function (commandId, properties, sequence) {
    if(commandId=='ElementWithStyleOptionsOpen') {
          //Remove styles that have the word Colored
          jQuery('li.ms-cui-menusection-items:contains("Colored")').remove();
    }
}
```